# sql server how do I set a default schema for my user given that I login as a group member

Tags: sql-server

So I login to a SQL Server database using Windows authentication - that's the rules - and I think it authorises me because I'm a member of a group - the name that I get when I run select system_user does not appear in select * from sys.database_principals.

I want to change the default schema for my user - ideally in exactly one database (not everything on that server)

How do I do it - given that I don't exist in that table?

Comment: What does `SELECT ORIGINAL_LOGIN(), SUSER_NAME()` show when ran in the database in question?

Answer (score 0):

After you login and use your database check what is inside of sys.user_token

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-user-token-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

```
select name from sys.user_token
```

Change default schema for those database principals.

Comment: there's only one thing inside that - which is a big long sid.... I'd be worried about affecting anyone else who logs in under the same group?

Comment: Yes. Everyone else connecting to this particular database as this particular principal will have default schema changed.

Comment: @DarrenOakey, If you want to change your default schema without changing the default schema for other Windows group members, you'll need your user account to added to the database to specify a different default schema.